# Royale-Apache Error: "This tag could not be resolved to an ActionScript class. It will be ignored."

Tags: mxml, apache-royale

I'm a NewBie with Royale-Apache, When I'm running "helloWorld" program.
But I don't know why error: "This tag could not be resolved to an ActionScript class. It will be ignored." away show when I run `mxmlc src/hello.mxml`(I use @apache-royale/royale-js npm) in teminal.

My code here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="library://ns.apache.org/royale/mx">
    <mx:initialView>
        <mx:View>
            <mx:Label text="Hello" />
        </mx:View>
    </mx:initialView>
</mx:Application>
```

My Folder :

[image]

Output:
[image]
I have two question:

1. Where did I go wrong?
2. What is mxmlns:mx/js/j/s tag at head?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you run HelloWorld example under 
<path-to-royale-asjs>\examples\royale\HelloWorld\src\main\royale\HelloWorld.mxml
?

Comment: may you please share the full compiler output ?

Comment: I have updated the output, Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding +configname=flex as an mxmlc option

Comment: Sorry, Can you tell me where I should add +configname=flex ?

Comment: After mxmlc

See
https://apache.github.io/royale-docs/migrate-an-existing-app/migrate-from-flex

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe is  <mx:initialView> tag
initialView is only for jewel application component, because jewell application is not  a view component.
If you use mx emulation, the mx:Application is a view component, so you only need remove the initialView tag.

But IMO if you havent any program to migrate, is better start with jewel library , because mx is not completed, and is only for mocking purposes.